# Creating Custom View, Android Studio

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I want to create a new Widget for my application using the creation of a CustomView. I went through the documentation of Creating Custom Views from : http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html

Can someone help me with a complete implementation of a custom created View.

The widget that I want to create is a counter widget.
[image]

Comment: Convert number to String, separate characters and reverse them and fill them into custom texts from right to left.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by custom texts?

Comment: For the number with orange box. Because you may also want to set custom fonts, you have to create custom text view class. You will need only a horizontal linear layout to show all textview.

Comment: How do I put the commas after every three digits?

Comment: It will be just imageviews between textviews.

Comment: Is there any way the thickness of the text i draw, be controlled?

Comment: use android:textStyle="bold" in layout.

Comment: Is there any way of controlling the thickness of the text i draw, using the paint object?

Comment: @ArjunIssar that font (for the numbers as blocks) is beautiful. Would you share what that is?

Answer (score 0):

The counter you are thinking can be implemented by using rectangles and then drawing text over them. The 'commas' can be drawn using UTF-8 encoded string.

You can count the length of the string, then reverse the string and then run a loop to draw them in the manner suggest above (from right to left). Insert a comma after every three iterations. Hope it helps you.